# HTML5 Canvas is very slow in google chrome and chromium but others are fast

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making a canvas scatter chart with 15,000 points. Each points contains 2 circles. It works perfectly in Firefox and Safari (takes 200ms) but in chrome it takes (1500ms). Here is my code i tried.

```
// dataUpdate has 15000 points
dataUpdate.forEach(function(d, i) {

    var x = getXYvalue(d, "x"),
        y = getXYvalue(d, "y"),
        size = getSymbolSize(d);

    context.save();
    context.translate(x, y);

    if (outerFillColor || outerStrokeColor) {

        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = fillColor;
        context.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
        context.lineWidth = outerStrokeWidth;

        context.arc(0, 0, size, 0, Math.PI * 2);

        if (outerFillColor) {
            context.fill();
        }
        if (outerStrokeColor && outerStrokeWidth) {
            context.stroke();
        }
        context.closePath();
    }

    if (innerFillColor || innerStrokeColor) {

        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = fillColor;
        context.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
        context.lineWidth = innerStrokeWidth;
        context.arc(0, 0, size / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);

        if (innerFillColor) {
            context.fill();
        }
        if (innerStrokeColor && innerStrokeWidth) {
            context.stroke();
        }
        context.closePath();
    }
    context.restore();
}
```

Comment: use a for loop for chrum - run [this benchmark](https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach) yourself and see. `forEach` is slower than a for loop - use a reveres for loop to get even more speed in chrum!! (also try array#map - apparently that's faster at least in firefox, I have no benchmark for that though)

Comment: having said that - that benchmark may be flawed - and 15000 is not that big really!

Comment: avoid save/restore in a loop, that's a lot of memory used for nothing, prefer a setTransform strategy. Also, try to sort your points by fillStyle lineWidth and strokeStyle, then create a single path per color and call appropriate methods only for these compound pathes. closePath calls are useless. And for micro-optimization, avoid to get your points coordinates through function calls, store these directly in your points (`var x = d.x` etc.)